# Invalid argument error while posting form data using JQuery ajax

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a webapplications in which i have to show search results without submitting the form. So i have used `$.ajax()` function of jQuery. Have a look at it

```
$('#search').click(function() {
                        alert("submit handler has fired");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'cityResults.htm',
                            data: $('#cityDetails').serialize(),
                            type: 'json',
                            success: function(data){ 
                                alert(data);
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                            }
                        });
                        return false;//suppress natural form submission
                    });
```

Here is my HTML markup. I am using Spring MVC 3 Framework

```
<form:form id="cityDetails" method="post"
                    action="cityResults.htm">
                    <table class="tdbgact border">
                        <tr>
                            <th>State:&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></th>
                            <td>
                            <form:select path = "state" id = "state">
                            <form:option value="">---Select</form:option>
                            <form:options items="${stateList}"/>
                            </form:select>
                           </td>                        
                           <th><form:checkbox path="status" value="Active"/>Active</th></td> 
                           <td colspan="5"><th><form:checkbox path="status" value="Inactive"/>Inactive</th></td>
                            <tr>   
                            <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="search" class="buttonSubmit" value="City" /></td>
                            </tr>
                         </tr>   
                    </table>
```

This is my Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cityResults.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)        
public @ResponseBody String schemeResults(ModelMap model ,@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")CityMaster bean, 
           BindingResult result) {
    functionName = "cityResults";
      List<CityMaster> cities = new ArrayList() ;
     logger.info("In "+className+" - "+functionName+" ");
     if(result.hasErrors())
     {

     } 
     else{
     ApplicationContext context = 
          new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
   MasterJDBCTemplate dao = 
   (MasterJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("masterJDBCTemplate");   
   String[] cityStatus = bean.getStatus();
   if(cityStatus == null)
   {

   }
   cities = dao.cityList(bean);
   model.addAttribute("cityList", cities ); 
     }
     return cities.get(0).getCity();
}
```

I get an error in the alert box saying Invalid Argument.Which means my ajax call fails. That means i have to change my controllers code. What changes do i have to do  ? Or is there anything else i am missing.

Comment: look in the console to see what you're getting back from the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might help you mapping your controller and returning json in response body.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody-demystified.html?ModPagespeed=noscript

[Returning JsonObject using @ResponseBody in SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204048/returning-jsonobject-using-responsebody-in-springmvc)

Comment: I have not include the POST type in AJAX call. And thanks the link helped !