# How to return JsonObject in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting a JsonObject that i need to return it as a raw json in spring mvc in the controller.
Using @ResponseBody doesn't work. So it's either i fix in the controller or i render it in a jsp , so any idea about any of these 2 solutions?
Note that i don't always know the type of the object returned in the json

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning JsonObject using @ResponseBody in SpringMVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204048/returning-jsonobject-using-responsebody-in-springmvc)

Comment: Using toString is what i have right now , i am looking for a different method since that function is consuming a lot of memory

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to return String? If so, use Json encoder and decoder. For example, `JSON-lib.jar` can be used to do these.

Comment: I can return a string , but i have a big application and using the toString method is using a lot of heap space which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few links that will help you

[Returning JsonObject using @ResponseBody in SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204048/returning-jsonobject-using-responsebody-in-springmvc)

[Spring configure @ResponseBody JSON format](http://Spring%20configure%20@ResponseBody%20JSON%20format)