# How to check JSON in response body with mockMvc

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, spring-test-mvc

This is my method inside my controller which is annotated by `@Controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getServerAlertFilters/{serverName}/", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject getServerAlertFilters(@PathVariable String serverName) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        List<FilterVO> filteredAlerts = alertFilterService.getAlertFilters(serverName, "");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.addAll(filteredAlerts);
        json.put(SelfServiceConstants.DATA, jsonArray);
        return json;
    }
```

I am expecting `{"data":[{"useRegEx":"false","hosts":"v2v2v2"}]}` as my json.

And this is my JUnit test:

```
@Test
    public final void testAlertFilterView() {       
        try {           
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/getServerAlertFilters/v2v2v2/").session(session)
                    .accept("application/json"))
                    .andDo(print()).andReturn();
            String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
            LOG.info(content);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the console output:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 406
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

Even `result.getResponse().getContentAsString()` is an empty string.

Can someone please suggest how to get my JSON in my JUnit test method so that I can complete my test case.

Comment: Please note that you received an http error code 406 (not acceptable request error), that's why your body is empty

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I use TestNG for my unit testing. But in Spring Test Framework they both looks similar. So I believe your test be like below

```
@Test
public void testAlertFilterView() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/getServerAlertFilters/v2v2v2/").
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json("{'data':[{'useRegEx':'false','hosts':'v2v2v2'}]}"));
    }
```

If you want check check json Key and value you can use jsonpath 
`.andExpect(jsonPath("$.yourKeyValue", is("WhatYouExpect")));`

You might find that`content().json()` are not solveble please add

`import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;`

Comment: I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError: org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/JSONAssert` when tried the solution (used in spring's `JsonExpectationsHelper`)

Comment: It can happen due to different reasons.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756989/2940265

Comment: @user7294900 possibly you should add `jsonassert` library to your runtime dependencies. For example from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.skyscreamer/jsonassert).

Answer (score 11):

The `406 Not Acceptable` status code means that Spring couldn't convert the object to json. You can either make your controller method return a String and do `return json.toString();` or configure your own `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`. Check this similar question [Returning JsonObject using @ResponseBody in SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204048/returning-jsonobject-using-responsebody-in-springmvc)

Answer (score 9):

You can try the below for get and post methods

```
@Autowired
private MuffinRepository muffinRepository;

@Test
public void testGetMethod throws Exception(){
    Muffin muffin = new Muffin("Butterscotch");
    muffin.setId(1L);
    
    BddMockito.given(muffinRepository.findOne(1L)).
        willReturn(muffin);
        
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
        get("/muffins/1")).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.status().isOk()).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.content().string("{\"id\":1, "flavor":"Butterscotch"}"));    
}

//Test to do post operation
@Test
public void testPostMethod throws Exception(){
    Muffin muffin = new Muffin("Butterscotch");
    muffin.setId(1L);
    
    BddMockito.given(muffinRepository.findOne(1L)).
        willReturn(muffin);
        
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
        post("/muffins")
        .content(convertObjectToJsonString(muffin))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.content().json(convertObjectToJsonString(muffin))); 
}
```

If the response is empty then make sure to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods on the `Entity` your repository is working with:

```
//Converts Object to Json String
private String convertObjectToJsonString(Muffin muffin) throws JsonProcessingException{
    ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectWriter().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    return writer.writeValueAsString(muffin);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways to check JSON responses. Lemme guide you through both of them, (taking test method from the question above, and assuming response `{"data":[{"useRegEx":"false","hosts":"v2v2v2"}]}` as given above)

Method 1) Asserting complete JSON

```
@Test
public final void testAlertFilterView() {       
    mockMvc.perform(get("/getServerAlertFilters/v2v2v2/")
           .contentType("application/json"))
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           // you may even read bigger json responses from file and convert it to string, instead of simply hardcoding it in test class
           .andExpect(content().json("{"data":[{"useRegEx":"false","hosts":"v2v2v2"}]}"))     
}
```

Method 2) Asserting specific key-value of response (not writing redundant piece of code)

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data[0].useRegEx").value(false))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data[0].hosts").value("v2v2v2"));
```

Another thing you might need is the import statement,

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check a few values in a specific field of JSON

```
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message",
    AllOf.allOf(
        StringContains.containsString("name: must not be null"),
        StringContains.containsString("type: must not be null")
    )));
```

How it looks in the test class. JUnit4.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.hamcrest.core.AllOf;
import org.hamcrest.core.StringContains;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class YourControllerTest {

  @Mock
  private YourService service;

  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(new YourController(service))
        .setControllerAdvice(new YourExceptionHandler())
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
        .build();
  }

  @Test
  public void yourControllerMethodName_400_validation() throws Exception {
    String path = "/orders/{orderId}/items";
    Integer orderId = 123;

    YourRequestDto requestDto = YourTestFactory.buildYourRequestDto();
    requestDto.setName(null);
    requestDto.setType(null);

    YourResponseDto expected = YourTestFactory.buildYourResponseDto(requestDto);

    Mockito
        .when(service.someMethod(orderId, requestDto))
        .thenReturn(expected);

    mvc
        .perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(path, orderId)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(requestDto))
        )
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message",
            AllOf.allOf(
                StringContains.containsString("name: must not be null"),
                StringContains.containsString("type: must not be null")
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's work to me