# How can I test if a jSON object is the same as I POSTED it using Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, mockito

Here is my endpoint :

```
 @PostMapping("/email/registration")
  public Data registration(@RequestBody Data data, HttpServletRequest 
  httpServletRequest) throws Exception {
  emailSenderService.pushEmail(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI(),          
  emailSenderService.sendConfirmationEmail(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI(), data));
  emailSenderService.consumeEmail(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
  return data;
  }
```

And here is my test(of course it's not working) :

```
  @Test
  public void testRegistrationConfirmation() throws Exception {
      Data testData = new Data();
      when(testData).thenReturn(testData);
      mockMvc.perform(
              post("/email/registration")
                      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .content(asJsonString(testData)))
              .andExpect(status().isOk())
              .andExpect(testData);
  }
```

I would like to see if the give object is the same as the return object, preferably without filling all the fields with values.

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check JSON in response body with mockMvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482934/how-to-check-json-in-response-body-with-mockmvc)

Answer (score 0):

It could be more elegant but you can use Jackson to make the json for you:

```
@Test
  public void testRegistrationConfirmation() throws Exception {
      Data testData = new Data();
      when(testData).thenReturn(testData);
      mockMvc.perform(
              post("/email/registration")
                      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .content(asJsonString(testData)))
              .andExpect(status().isOk())
              .andExpect(content().string(equalTo(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(testData))));
  }
```

Comment: .andExpect(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(testData));
says it cannot be applied to String

Comment: @Vitya sorry sloppy typing, I have updated the answer.