# Submitting a Form with Angular JS and Spring MVC

Tags: java, angularjs, forms, spring-mvc, angularjs-forms

I am noob with Angular JS and I am having difficulties to submit a simple Form using Angular JS and Spring MVC. I am getting this error:

> The requested resource is not available
>
> mock.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core'%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="security"uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Settings</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/workflow.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/upload.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.qtip.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo-small.png" />

</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('formSubmit', []);

    app.controller('FormSubmitController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.list = [];
            $scope.headerText = 'AngularJS Post Form Spring MVC example: Submit below form';
            $scope.submit = function() {

                var formData = {
                        "name1" : $scope.name1,
                        "name2" : $scope.name2,
                        "name3" : $scope.name3,
                };

                var response = $http.post('submitmock', formData);
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.list.push(data);
                });
                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
                });

                //Empty list data after process
                $scope.list = [];

            };
        }]);
</script>
<style>        
input.ng-invalid {    
    border: 2px red solid;
    }
</style>
<body ng-app="formSubmit">

    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">


        <form  data-ng-submit="submit()" data-ng-controller="FormSubmitController"> <!-- novalidate prevents HTML5 validation since we will be validating ourselves -->
            <table border="1">                          
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <label>Name Line 1:</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="form-group">                            
                            <input type="text" name="name1" class="form-control" ng-model="name1" required ng-Maxlength="40">   
                            <p ng-show="userForm.name1.$error.required"  class="help-block">Name is required.</p>
                            <p ng-show="userForm.name1.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Maximum 40 characters</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <label>Name Line 2:</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="form-group">                    
                        <input type="text" name="name2" class="form-control" ng-model="name2" ng-Maxlength="40"> 
                        <p ng-show="userForm.name2.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Maximum 40 characters</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <label>Name Line 3:</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="form-group">                        
                        <input type="text" name="name3" class="form-control" ng-model="name3" ng-Maxlength="40"> 
                        <p ng-show="userForm.name3.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Maximum 40 characters</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <h4>You submitted below data through post:</h4>
                             <pre>Form data ={{list}}</pre>
                    </td>   
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>   

            </form>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

> mockController.java

```
package com.opessoftware.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.opessoftware.beans.MockForm;
import com.opessoftware.beans.SettingsForm;

@Controller
public class MockController {

    @RequestMapping("/mock")
    public String getSettingsPage(){
        return "mock";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/angularjs-http-service-ajax-post-code-example", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView httpServicePostExample( ModelMap model ) {
        return new ModelAndView("httpservice_post");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submitmock", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody MockForm getMock(@RequestBody MockForm mockForm){      
        return mockForm;
    }



}
```

Please Help.

Spring version = 3.2.0 RELEASE

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I cannot see in your mock.jsp the taglib, claiming it is a JSP.

Comment: I just added but it`s not the problem :(

Comment: why do u use jsp?. Angular is substitution of outdated jsp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have your form structure like below, there would be `formData` in scope model which will contains `name1`, `name2` & `name3`, You also missed to add form name which should be `name="myForm"`

**Markup**

```
<form data-ng-submit="submit()" name="myForm" data-ng-controller="FormSubmitController">
    <!-- novalidate prevents HTML5 validation since we will be validating ourselves -->
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label>Name Line 1:</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name1" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.name1" required ng-Maxlength="40">
                    <p ng-show="userForm.name1.$error.required" class="help-block">Name is required.</p>
                    <p ng-show="userForm.name1.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Maximum 40 characters</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label>Name Line 2:</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name2" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.name2" ng-Maxlength="40">
                    <p ng-show="userForm.name2.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Maximum 40 characters</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label>Name Line 3:</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name3" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.name3" ng-Maxlength="40">
                    <p ng-show="userForm.name3.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Maximum 40 characters</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h4>You submitted below data through post:</h4>
                <pre>Form data ={{list}}</pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

After making this changes in Markup you need to sort your controller with some code, As you server side method is asking for `mockForm` parameter, you should pass `formData` value in it.

**Code**

```
$scope.formData = {}; //should set object on init.
$scope.submit = function() {
    var response = $http.post('submitmock',{ mockForm: formData}); //passing mockForm
    response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.list.push(data);
    });
    response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({
            data: $scope.formData //used formData model here
        }));
    });

    //Empty list data after process
    $scope.list = [];
};
```

Comment: Thank you, now I am getting the JSON String but it's returning the **response.error** instead of **response.success**. I can't post pictures here but it says this: `Exception details: : {"data""{"name1":323", "name2":2323", "name3":"bf"}}`. The JSON is coming but its coming through a failure :(

Comment: @JoséMendes look at this for further details http://stackoverflow.com/a/19205116/2435473 ..looks like issue on server side