# java jsonobject "value" and "num"

Tags: java, json

when using the javax json ObjectBuilder to build json, the output json string contains "value" and "num" in the json string. my web service is throw serialization error when the json contains "value" and "num". any one know why the output have "value" and "num"?

example:

```
JsonObject addProductRequest = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("OrderID", orderId)
            .add("Product", productId)
            .add("Quantity", qty)
            .add("access_token", access_token)
            .build();
```

output:

```
{
  "OrderID": {
    "num": 15498
  },
  "ProductID": {
    "num": 20
  },
  "Quantity": {
    "num": 1
  },
  "access_token": {
    "value": "1f6c689d-6956-4f8e-b259-9030d57bec4b"
  }
}
```

when I switch to using google.gson.JsonObject, the output dont have the "value" and "num" string, which my web service accepts and every thing seems to work fine.
example

```
 com.google.gson.JsonObject addProductRequest = new com.google.gson.JsonObject();
    addProductRequest.addProperty("OrderID", orderId);
    addProductRequest.addProperty("Product", productId);
    addProductRequest.addProperty("Quantity", qty);
    addProductRequest.addProperty("access_token", access_token);
```

output:

```
{  "OrderID": 15499,  "Product": 20,  "Quantity": 1,  "access_token": "3241cfd4-7b6c-4eac-b2bb-9b2b0c780831"}
```

Comment: What are you serializing? Show us the POJO and show us the code.

Comment: updated with code. there is no POCO, just using the builder.

Comment: And where are you getting the resulting `String` value? Or how do you output `addProductRequest` ?

Comment: the result string ouputed by rest-assured log.

Comment: You'd have to check how rest-assured logs it.  Calling `addProductRequest.toString()` returns the expected json `String` value for me, with the glassfish 1.0.4 implementation of `javax.json`.

Comment: please insert how you fill the data and print the result

Comment: the problem seems to be from the RequestSpecification body. if I set the body with a com.google.gson.JsonObject object, rest assured will send the body in the correct format(with out "value" and "num"). but if I set the body with a javax.json.JsonObject object, there seems to be conversion problem, the body is not in the correct format(with "value" and "num").

example
.body(object, ObjectMapperType.GSON)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest Assured seems to use Gson to serialize POJOs (which is what you should be using as response entities) to the response body.

Gson doesn't know anything about `javax.json`. The implementation of `javax.json` that you are using basically has this format for its `JsonObject`:

```
private static final class JsonObjectImpl extends AbstractMap<String, JsonValue> implements JsonObject {
    private final Map<String, JsonValue> valueMap;      // unmodifiable
```

Since this is a `Map`, Gson uses special serializing, iterating through its `entrySet` and using each `Entry` as a JSON key-value pair (within a JSON object).

In this case, the `entrySet` returns

```
@Override
public Set<Entry<String, JsonValue>> entrySet() {
    return valueMap.entrySet();
}
```

where the `valueMap` contains all the values you added with `add` in your builder. For example, for

```
.add("OrderID", 1)
```

it will have added an entry with the `String` key `OrderID` and the `JsonValue` value of

```
// Optimized JsonNumber impl for int numbers.
private static final class JsonIntNumber extends JsonNumberImpl {
    private final int num;
```

Notice the `num` field.

So Gson will now see a value of this `JsonIntNumber` type. It considers it a POJO and so serializes it as a JSON object with its fields as key-value pairs. It therefore produces

```
{
    "num": 15498
}
```

---

`com.google.gson.JsonObject` is a known type to `Gson`. It knows that it is special and not a custom POJO type. It can therefore write it directly, instead of having to serialize it further.

---

This is similar to a question which I answered here:

- [Returning JsonObject using @ResponseBody in SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204048/returning-jsonobject-using-responsebody-in-springmvc)

Comment: Thanks. that explains it.