# Why does Spring MVC report "No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONObject"?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I want to return a JSON made of two strings and don't know how to implement it. Here is my code:

```
 @PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<> createUser(@RequestBody User user ) {

    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();

    if (userService.userExists(user)) {

        responseJson.put("status", "User with that username already exists.");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseJson, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    responseJson.put("status", "User created.");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseJson, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I've got `Json » 20160810` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` in my pom.xml and I'm still getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONObject` Why doesn't Jackson automatically converts my JSON? It's a standard one, just simple key:value. Maybe there is better way to create simple JSONs using some class in jackson.core so I don't have to inlude Json lib in my project and jackson automatically converts them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you're using two JSON parsing libraries. Instead of creating a `JSONObject`, create Jackson's equivalent [`ObjectNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html).

Assuming you have access to the `ObjectMapper` used by your Spring MVC stack

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

use it to create and populate the `ObjectNode`

```
ObjectNode jsonObject = mapper.createObjectNode();
jsonObject.put("status", "User with that username already exists.");
// don't forget to change return type to support this
return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Since this is a Jackson type, Jackson knows how to serialize it.

It doesn't know how to serialize `JSONObject`. Some of the following explanation comes from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204048/returning-jsonobject-using-responsebody-in-springmvc).

Essentially, Spring MVC uses [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html) implementations to handle values returned by `@RequestMapping` (`@PostMapping`) annotated methods. For `ResponseEntity`, that implementation is [`HttpEntityMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/HttpEntityMethodProcessor.html).

This implementation simply loops through a collection of [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) instances, checks if an instance can serialize the `body` of the `ResponseEntity`, and uses it if it can.

Unfortunately, Jackson's `HttpMessageConverter` implementation, [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html), uses an `ObjectMapper` to serialize these objects and `ObjectMapper` cannot serialize `JSONObject` because it can't discover any properties in the class (ie. bean getters).

Jackson's `HttpMessageConverter` can't do it and neither can all the other ones that are registered by default. That's why Spring MVC reports "no converter".

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONObject
```

An alternative solution is to serialize the `JSONObject` yourself to a `String` and pass that to the `ResponseEntity`. Obviously you'll want to change your return type to support `String`. In this case, Spring MVC will use a [`StringHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html). However, you'll want to specify the `application/json` content type yourself because it doesn't add it. For example,

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
return new ResponseEntity<>(responseJson.toString(), headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Jackson` does not know about `org.json.JSONObject`, use  [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) instead for `key/value` pair.

**Update after comment:**

> Could you write me an example how would you use it? I find it a bit
>   confusing

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Map<String, String> responseJson = new HashMap<>();
        if (userService.userExists(user)) {
            responseJson.put("status",
                    "User with that username already exists.");
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(responseJson);
            return new ResponseEntity<JsonNode>(jsonNode,
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        responseJson.put("status", "User created.");
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(responseJson);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonNode, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```