# $.get is returning the empty response

Tags: jquery

I am calling a below jquery call

```
var url = "demo/getResponseData"
$.get(url,function(responseData, status){
 console.log("dtFetched:",responseData);
 alert("status" + status);
});
```

The back end spring boot code is as below

```
@RequestMapping(path="demo/getResponseData")
    public JSONObject getResponseData()  throws IOException, JSONException{
        System.out.println("================================Called from JavaScript");
        HttpClientManager httpClientMgr = new HttpClientManager();
        List<JSONObject> responseString= httpClientMgr.getResponseData();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
         object.put("data", responseString);
        System.out.println("============OUTPUT====================" + responseString);
        //return responseString;
        return object;
    }
```

I am able to see the output in java console, however 'responseData' is empty. What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Wrong variable name and missing `)` at the end. Please fix your typos

Comment: I just pasted a part of the code, please note that I do not have any script errors in the code. Is it something that each of the JSONObject in the List need to be mapped to a VO object? Currently I'm creating JSONObject and putting key and values and then adding that json to the list.

Comment: Have you tried looking in your browser's _Network_ console? What does the response body look like?

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the replying. I solved the issue by creation the VO objects and then putting it in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You are logging the wrong variable for response in javascript

```
var url = "demo/getResponseData"
$.get(url,function(responseData, status){
 console.log("dtFetched:",responseData); // <- fix this line
 alert("status" + status);
})
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it is a typo, i'm using the correct variable.

Comment: hey. i am suing ur paytm package. i have done evrythng as u said. but wen i click the pay now button the page shows "transaction being processed" and then redirects me to a blank page like payment/api/status. why is it not taking me to paytm website?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the  dataType

```
var url = "demo/getResponseData"
$.get(url,function(responseData, status){
    console.log("dtFetched:",responseData);
    alert("status" + status);
}, "json");
```

Also add @ResponseBody to the controller

```
public @ResponseBody JSONObject getResponseData()
```

Also according to [this answer in so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204048/returning-jsonobject-using-responsebody-in-springmvc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), it is better to return the JSON as string.

```
@RequestMapping(path="demo/getResponseData")
public @ResponseBody String getResponseData()  throws IOException, JSONException{
    System.out.println("================================Called from JavaScript");
    HttpClientManager httpClientMgr = new HttpClientManager();
    List<JSONObject> responseString= httpClientMgr.getResponseData();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
     object.put("data", responseString);
    System.out.println("============OUTPUT====================" + responseString);
    //return responseString;
    return object.toString();
}
```

Comment: As it is a RestController we do not need to add @ResponseBody spring boot will take care of it., however I solved the problem by creating the VO objects and then returning the list